# Waiting for couple of observable to finish with/without sequence Retrofit2 with rxjava - Android

Tags: android, rx-java, retrofit2, rx-android

I use retrofit 2 with rxjava extension

I have 3 Observables which will do 3 different things

```
Observable<String> observable1 = RetrofitInterface.GetByID(id);
Observable<String> observable2 = RetrofitInterface.GetByKey(key);
Observable<String> observable3 = RetrofitInterface.GetByValue(value);
```

now in somehow user will have the option to run all of them together

to run them i do this:

```
observable1.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .unsubscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .subscribe(new Subscriber<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted() {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable e) {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNext(String str1) {
                        // do some stuff here
                    }
                });
```

User have 3 options here,

1. Run each and every observable separately
2. Run three of them together and wait them to finish to show result
3. Run them sequentially and get the result one by one.

**how can we do the last 2 options in Rxjava having those three observables sent to us by Retrofit ?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second options you can reach using zip, like this:

```
public class ExampleUnitTest {
    @Test
    public void testSample() throws Exception {
        Observable<String> observable1 = Observable.just("I");
        Observable<String> observable2 = Observable.just("Love");
        Observable<String> observable3 = Observable.just("RxJava");

        Observable.zip(observable1, observable2, observable3,
                (s1, s2, s3) -> {
                    return String.format("%s %s %s", s1, s2, s3);
                }
        ).subscribe(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

It will print `I Love RxJava`. Take a look at [zip documentations](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/zip.html).

The second one you achieve with concat, check it out:

```
public class ExampleUnitTest {
    @Test
    public void testSample() throws Exception {
        Observable<String> observable1 = Observable.just("I");
        Observable<String> observable2 = Observable.just("Love");
        Observable<String> observable3 = Observable.just("RxJava");

        Observable.concat(observable1, observable2, observable3)
                .subscribe(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

It will print:

```
I
Love
RxJava
```

Take a look at [concat documentation](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/concat.html) too.

Best regards.

Comment: Do not forget about handling errors when using `zip`, for example if one of observables terminates with onError|onCompleted, other observables may not emit any value.